# How to convert UTF-16 symbol code to nvarchar2 in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, internationalization, nchar

I have a UTF-16 code, which is `\D83D`, and I want to get a symbol out of this code. I need some function like `chr` that returns `nvarchar2` string. Like this:

```
select convert_utf16_to_nchar('\D83D') from dual;
```

Comment: You do realize, though, that `\D83D` alone is not a valid UTF-16 code, right? It's the high surrogate of (many) surrogate pairs; by itself it is not a "symbol" of any kind.

Comment: @mathguy Yes, I do. The main problem was to transfer an `nvarchar2` record with this symbol from one DB to another. I've managed to get the so called "UTF-16 code" by using `asciistr` function but didn't get how I can reproduce this symbol by this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `unistr`

> **UNISTR** takes as its argument a text literal or an expression that resolves to character data and returns it in the national character set. The national character set of the database can be either AL16UTF16 or UTF8. UNISTR provides support for Unicode string literals by letting you specify the Unicode encoding value of characters in the string. This is useful, for example, for inserting data into NCHAR columns.

Example

```
SELECT UNISTR('abc\00e5\00f1\00f6') FROM DUAL;

UNISTR
------
abcåñö
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Roman , you are very welcome ;)